# Android, focus goes from a view to another one after orientation change

Tags: java, android, focus, onrestoreinstancestate, android-compound-view

I created a custom compound view, something like

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/label" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edittext" />
</merge>
```

Of course this is a simplified version.

I've managed to save and restore the view instance state in the java class bound to the view, nonetheless i overrided

```
@Override
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchThawSelfOnly(container);
}
```

This should prevent save/restore instance state calls to be dispatched to the child views (the `TextView` and the `EditText`).

Now i have a fragment containing two of those custom views, with different ids; when an orientation change occurs, the focus always goes to the first `EditText` after the fragment is recreated. I can't understand why.

For example, let's call edittext1 and edittext2 the edittexts belonging to the custom views with id1 and id2, this is what happens:
edittext2 has focus -> orientation change happens -> onSaveInstaceState called on both view -> edittext2 onChangeFocus called (from true to false) -> onRestoreInstanceStateCalled on both view -> edittext1 onFocusChange called (from false to true).

I don't want this to happen, what I'm missing?